# Passing a param from a view to controller. Then back to a view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms, ruby-on-rails-4, parameter-passing

The goal is to capture an input from a form and then after the controller and service are done with it display the result on another view. The main problem is the interaction between the controller and the form view. The view should pass the captured input as a parameter to the controller and go on its merry way. How do I properly capture the parameter and pass it to my controller?

```
# controller
class CheckNumberController < ApplicationController
  require_relative '../services/number_check_modulo'
  def get_cert_number(cert)
    @cert_id = cert
  end

  def show_check_number
    checking_policy_number = Get_policy_check_digit.new(@cert_id) # Creates a new instance of the "Get_policy_check_digit" class
                                                                 # From number_check.rb
    @check_number = checking_policy_number.create_check_digit     # Runs the "create_check_digit" method from the "Get_policy_check_digit" class
  end
end

# service 'app/services/number_check_modulo' required in the controller shown above
class Get_policy_check_digit
  def initialize(cert_id)
    #instance variable
    @cert = cert_id
  end

  def create_check_digit
    cert_id_6 = @cert.to_s
    cert_id_6.slice!(0)
    cert_id_6.to_i
    cert_id_6 % 7
  end
end
```

I am currently using the form helper form_tag in my view. After the user submits a number the page will redirect to what will be the output display page.

```
# Form view
<H1>Enter Cert Number below</H1>

<%= form_tag('show_check_number', method: 'get') do %>
    <%= text_field_tag(:cert) %>
    <%= submit_tag("Submit") %>
<% end %>
```

This page simply shows the result of the calculations done by the service 'app/services/number_check_modulo'

```
# View that shows the result
<h1>Your check number is <%= @check_number %></h1>
```

I'm fairly new to this but I think I'm on the right track.

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something but I don't see you doing anything like `params[:cert]` to get the value of `:cert`; is that what you're missing?

Comment: Your class naming and methods name are pretty confusing. Anyway, it should be this: `checking_policy_number = Get_policy_check_digit.new(params[:cert])`. The method `get_cert_number(cert)` is useless here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you this refactor:

```
# controller
require 'app/services/number_check_modulo'    
class CheckNumberController < ApplicationController

  def show_check_number
    policy_check_digit = PolicyCheckDigit.new(params[:cert])
    @check_number = policy_check_digit.create_check_digit
  end
end

# app/services/number_check_modulo
class PolicyCheckDigit
  def initialize(cert_id)
    @cert = cert_id
  end

  def create_check_digit
    cert_id_6 = @cert.to_s
    cert_id_6.slice!(0)
    cert_id_6.to_i
    cert_id_6 % 7
  end
end
```

Comment: I tried to refactor the way you showed but I'm getting an error. "NameError in CheckNumberController#show_check_number" "uninitialized constant CheckNumberController::PolicyCheckDigit". I don't see why this should happen. I the spelling is correct since I just did a copy paste of PolicyCheckDigit.

Comment: You have to restart your server, and eventually put the require inside the class block of the controller (requires the files when the class is loaded and not when the file is read by the system)

Answer (score 2):

try to change method show_check_number to this

```
def show_check_number
  checking_policy_number = Get_policy_check_digit.new(params[:cert]) 
  @check_number = checking_policy_number.create_check_digit    
end
```